# What is causing this error: (Could not find SDK "windowsIoT, Version=10.0.10240.0")?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, raspberry-pi2, iot, windows-10-universal, windows-10-iot-core

I am buiding a Universal Windows app that will run on a Raspberry Pi 2 that is running Windows IoT.  For some strange reason, I cannot build the project because I keep getting the following build error:

> Could not find SDK "windowsIoT, Version=10.0.10240.0"

I am using version 10.0.10586.0 of all the Windows references.  Why is it even looking for version 10.0.10240.0 in the first place?

Any ideas on how to fix this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you install the dev tools for Windows 10? It's a separate installer.

Comment: Yes, I had already installed that.

Answer (score 1):

There's a separate "knob" in the `.vcxproj` for the WindowsIoT Extension SDK version (i.e. separate from the "***TargetPlatformVersion***" that shows up in project properties.)

So, observe folder names under `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Windows Kits\10\Extension SDKs\WindowsIoT`: and then hand edit the `.vcxproj` to point at one the does exist (or expand References in Solution Explorer and modify Properties of the Windows IoT Extensions for the UWP entry):

```
<SDKReference Include="WindowsIoT, Version=10.0.17134.0">
    <Name>Windows IoT Extensions for the UWP</Name>
</SDKReference>
```

Answer (score 0):

After much consternation, I discovered that I had unnecessarily added References to the following unneeded NuGet Packages:

> Microsoft.IoT.DeviceCore
>      Microsoft.IoT.Devices

When I removed the above 2 unnecessary NuGetPackages from my projects, they build just fine.

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer.  i have the same issue.  How do you remove  those packages?

Comment: Right click on your solution in Visual Studio.  Select 'Manage NuGet Packages' on the drop down menu.  When the dialog opens, click on the 'Installed' tab at the upper left of the window.  Select the package that you want to remove.  Then, on the right side of the window, put a checkmark next to 'Project' to mark all projects in your solution.  Then click the 'Uninstall' button just below that on the right side of the window.